# .SHELLFLAGS assignment in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html#One-Shell):***

> ...You can modify `.SHELLFLAGS` to add the `-e` option to the shell which will
>   cause any failure anywhere in the command line to cause the shell to
>   fail...

***So, given the following makefile:***

```make
.SHELLFLAGS = -e -c

define cmd
echo true
true
endef

all::
    $(shell $(cmd))
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
truetrue
/bin/sh: 1: truetrue: not found
makefile:10: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Did you see that (in the 1st line of output)? ***truetrue?*** Where did it come from?

Let's compare it with the following ***identical*** makefile, where `-e` was not added to `.SHELLFLAGS`.


***The makefile, would be:***

```make
# Do you see the difference, from the previous Makefile?
# Here, the value is '-c' alone. No '-e' flag is present here!
.SHELLFLAGS = -c

define cmd
echo true
true
endef


all::
    $(shell $(cmd))
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
true true
```

Much better!

So, we have here 2 versions of makefile, both run **identical** commands, where the first version also added the `-e` flag to `.SHELLFLAGS`.

The results however - for the respective runs - were not consistent! We had:

1. Expands to the *trivial* command `true true`, which is analogous to the trivial command `: true` (i.e "ignore arguments..."), and therefore an exit-status: 0.

   - This was for the "simple" run, without the change in `.SHELLFLAGS`. (version 2).
2. As for the first run, Make went ahead, and condensed the command to `truetrue` (really?), hence: a meaningless command and a fatal error from the shell.

In summary: It seems that adding `-e` to `.SHELLFLAGS` is not that *innocent* as the documentation suggested above.

In fact, Make, then (when .SHELLFLAGS is modified to include `-e`), and only then - Make takes the liberty to do some more (unexpected?) modification to the command, resulting - for example - here with the command `truetrue` for a `true true` command.

Really?

(Versions-note: All versions supporting `.SHELLFLAGS`, which is 3.82 and up).

Comment: [Again.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163055/a-tentative-approach-to-execute-oneshell-in-makefile?noredirect=1#comment52214731_32163055) my suggestion would be to file a bug report. You are probably the first person in the history of  mankind who explores this particular combination of options and features. A public bug report is more likely to help than a long-forgotten Stackoverflow thread in case the second person in the history of  mankind ever comes  along.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve never understood using `$(shell ...)` in a recipe. There may be one or two
situations where it’s useful, but I see it constantly and I’ve yet to see one.

However, you’ll note that the documentation says that the value for
`.SHELLFLAGS` when you want to use the `-e` flag should be `-ec`, not `-e -c`.
Some versions of the Bourne shell do not accept multiple flags on the command
line: they must be a single set of flags. If you use `-ec` then your example
works.

The difference in behavior you’re seeing is in the treatment of newlines in
recipes: in some situations they’re removed along with the initial TAB, in other
situations they’re converted to a single space. I don’t know why adding a second
option to `.SHELLFLAGS` causes this but I agree with tripleee: you should
[file a bug](//savannah.gnu.org/bugs?func=additem&group=make).

Comment: The documentation says that the ***default*** may be `-ec`. But, using `.SHELLFLAGS`, renders the *default* behaviour non-relevant. In fact, assigning to `SHELL` a utility other than a *UNIX-shell*, `.SHELLFLAGS` will - probably - have to be something very different from the *default* (i.e. other than `-c` or `-ec`). So any default behavior has very little say here

Comment: And, I assume, that Make has to respect any `.SHELLFLAGS`, that the `SHELL` itself respects. UNIX-shells (excluding any weird, unused versions), **do** respect `-e -c`.

Comment: But, if you insist on a single-word value to `.SHELLFLAGS`, then, what about `.SHELLFLAGS=-eec`. Yes, a *bad* user, but still **very** valid. Now, running it, you'll see, that the run produces the **very same** errors, produced for `-e -c`.

Bottom line, they are all legitimate assignments to `.SHELLFLAGS` (from the perspective of **both**: Make, and the `SHELL`), still Make will fatally fail only some of them.

Comment: I didn't say there wasn't a bug here.  In fact I said there WAS a bug and that you should report it.  I said that if you use `-ec` then it works as expected, so if your goal is to fix a real problem and get something to work, then I've given you a solution.  If your goal is just to find bugs in GNU make, that's a very useful thing BUT it's not appropriate for StackOverflow which is a site dedicated to helping real programmers fix real problems in their real code.  If you want to report bugs in GNU make use Savannah or the bug-make@gnu.org mailing list, not StackOverflow.